# Program stop to running when calls a process

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to create a program that calls another process using CreateProcess. After some problems, I change my program to just open a known program:

> ```
> if( !CreateProcess( (LPWSTR)"C:\\Program Files\\Opera\\Opera.exe",   // No module name (use command line)
>     NULL,                       ,
>             // Command line
>     NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
>     NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
>     FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
>     0,              // No creation flags
>     NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
>     NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
>     &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
>     &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
> )
> ```

I found this example in msdn, but every time I run my program, windows (Vista) shows a error msg: The program stop running...

Does anybody know what is the problem?

Regards,
Leandro Lima

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
(LPWSTR)"C:\\Program Files\\Opera\\Opera.exe"
```

`LPWSTR` is a typedef for `wchar_t*`. So you're casting a plain string (array of chars, which will decay to a `const char*`) to a `wchar_t*`. The end result is likely not even null-terminated!

Either use `CreateProcessA` and drop the cast, or use a wide string:

```
 L"C:\\Program Files\\Opera\\Opera.exe",
```

Comment: Hi, I teste you sugestion but I wanna know why to use CreateProcessA instead CreateProcess.

Comment: `CreateProcessA` is a version that takes `LPCSTR` (i.e. `const char*`) as the first argument. `CreateProcessW` is another version that takes `LPCWSTR` (i.e. `const wchar_t*`). In Windows headers, there's a `#define CreateProcess CreateProcessA` or `#define CreateProcess CreateProcessW`, chosen depending on whether you compile with Unicode enabled (i.e. `/D_UNICODE`) or not. The default for new C++ projects in Visual Studio is Unicode enabled. Also, it is better to use `L""` over `CreateProcessA`, because Unicode APIs are native on WinNT family, and ANSI APIs convert to Unicode and call `...W`.

Comment: What's the diference between run my project with debug and release? Debug doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" is an error-description that is nobody telling anything.

Comment: @Leandro: ask it as a separate question.